# how to write a [(ngModel)] = "" dynamically on ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to create dynamic fields in ionic for my poll app

First . I have 2 arrays

[image]

then I'm trying to create the fields with a swich case

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let preguntas of LocalPreguntas">
      <ion-card >
        <ion-card-header color="primary">
          {{ preguntas.pregunta}}
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content [ngSwitch]="preguntas.tipo">
    
                  <!-- Respuesta Si o no-->
                  <div  *ngSwitchCase="4" style="display:block" >   
                      <ion-list radio-group  name="{{preguntas.id}}" [(ngModel)]="Form.radio_vf" required>
                          <ion-item >
                              <ion-label  color="dark">Si</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio value="Si"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>
                          
                            <ion-item  >
                              <ion-label  color="dark">No</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio value="No"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>

                       </ion-list>
                  </div>
        </ion-card-content>  
      </ion-card>
   </ion-list>
```

its all right

[image]

but logically this is wrong `[(ngModel)] = "Form.txt_cantidad"` because the app can repeat the question types

to fix that. I want to put the question id in the `[(ngModel)]`

```html
 <div  *ngSwitchCase="4" style="display:block" >   
 <ion-list radio-group  name="{{preguntas.id}}" [(ngModel)]="{{preguntas.id}}" required>
        <ion-item >
              <ion-label  color="dark">Si</ion-label>
              <ion-radio value="Si"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
                          
        <ion-item  >
              <ion-label  color="dark">No</ion-label>
              <ion-radio value="No"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

     </ion-list>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `{{ }}` that is in the ngModel, you don't need interpolation where you are using the input bindings syntax `[ ]` in your case you are using it in combination with the `( )` output syntax.

Comment: ok it work [(ngModel)]="preguntas.id"  .   but how can i  show  the model.. withconsole.log(ngModel); ????????

Comment: You want to see the value of LocalPreguntas? Just put it in a ```<pre> {{ LocalPreguntas | json }} </pre> ```

Comment: no i want to see the value of  subtended form

Comment: Well you don't have a form to begin with, so I don't think you can really few the value. I would personally recommend you to look into using `FormBuilder` in combination with `FormArray`s to dynamically create `formArray`s and `FormControl`s so you can actually have validation rules and so you can see the 'current value of the form`. See [this](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/) article for some extra help on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

look at Vf field. 
is an array inside another array

```
  public Form = {
        cliente:"",
        encueestaID:"",
        usuarioid:"",
        vf:{
          vf:{}
          },
        seleccionUnica:[],
        seleccionMultiple:[],
        tiempotipo:[],
        tipoCantidad:[],
        cantidad:[],
        1:""
   };
```

to write in this array I use 
the following code

```
 <div  *ngSwitchCase="4" style="display:block" >   
                      <ion-list radio-group  name="{{preguntas.id}}" [(ngModel)]="Form.vf.vf[preguntas.id]" required>
                          <ion-item >
                              <ion-label  color="dark">Si</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio value="Si"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>

                            <ion-item  >
                              <ion-label  color="dark">No</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio value="No"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>

                       </ion-list>
                  </div>
```

result
[image]